# Revert to original CSS on mouseout

Tags: css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion, mouseover

I'm trying to make an AjaxControlToolkit Accordion control change the header style on mouseover and mouseout. It works fine but when the user mouses over the currently selected header then leaves it the special CSS for selected headers is overwritten by the mouseout class that I've assigned. I'm just using `onmouseover="this.className='AccHover'"` and `onmouseout="this.className='AccMouseOut'"` in a `<div>` tag inside the accordions header sections.

Is there a way to remove the AccHover class on the mouseout event and have it revert back to either the unselected CSS style or the Selected header style depending on the accordion panes state automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

`onmouseover="this.classList.add('AccHover')"`

and

`onmouseout="this.classList.remove('AccHover')"`

EDIT: Ok I just remembered `classList` doesn't work in IE, I assume that's what you are testing in. In that case I would use something like:

`onmouseover="this.className = this.className + ' AccHover';"`

and

`onmouseout="this.className = this.className.replace('AccHover', '');"`

See example http://jsfiddle.net/RgRUN/2/

But I would call your own javascript function rather than write inline.

Comment: It's saying `this.classList` is undefined when I run it.